# Is there any simple way to add \n in r'' string in python

Tags: python, string, format

I need to add several paths into a single line string with a \n character at the end. For convenience, The key word r is added at the front of the string. In this case the character '\n' couldn't be display normally.

Ex.

```
str_output = r'name = %(name)s, some_dir = \\folder0\\..., description = "%(des)s\n'
print(str_output % {'name':'new', 'des':'new add one'})
```

The out put will display without line break. Currently I use string plus to by pass this problem. Such as:

```
str_output = r'name = %(name)s, some_dir = \\folder0\\..., description = "%(des)s' + '\n'
```

Instead of the previous define of str_output. I'm curious about is there any other convenience way to do this?  The string plus looks ugly in my codes. Thank you!

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is the `r` in front of the string - it treats each character literally and escape sequences aren't escaped.

Comment: Yes I know the function of the character r, but if I use this feature is it means the character '\n' couldn't be added?

Comment: Not with a raw string - `r'\n'` is the same as `'\\n'`, which prints `'\n'` and not a newline character.

Comment: Yes, but if it there is a simple way to add '\n' in raw string the code will look more directly and effective than mix with string plus. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string literal prefix `r` signifies a raw string, that is escape's are regular characters. If you really want to use raw strings, you can try something like:

```py
name = 'new'
des = 'new add one'
newline = '\n'
str_output = rf'name = {name}s, some_dir = \\folder0\\..., description = "{des}s{newline}s'
print(str_output)
```

Although this means that you'll have to bear the `newline` in every `dict`.

Another way of doing it which has a little more meaning:

```py
str_output = r'name = %(name)s, some_dir = \\folder0\\..., description = "%(des)s%(\n)s'
print(str_output % {'name':'new', 'des':'new add one', '\\n': '\n'})
```

Comment: It's really a new way to do it to me. It seems there is no elegance way to do this job in python. :( But it will not effect me like to use python programming.

Comment: Well strings are a pain in all languages, Python is one of the few that handles them "elegantly"

Answer (score 14):

I'm a little late to the party here but this was a recent requirement for myself.
I wanted a multiline axis label with LaTeX parsing for a 2-dimensional histogram in `matplotlib`.

My solution was to use parentheses to start line continuation, and then combine normal and raw strings to achieve the line break:

```py
xlabel=('Time of Flight (ToF)\n'
        r'[$\times10^3$ arb. units]')
```

Here’s how this looks:

[image: Here's a screen grab of the result]

This can be extended to more complex strings.

Answer (score 4):

The `r` you're putting before the start of your string literal indicates to Python that is is a "raw" string, and that escape sequences within it should be treated as regular characters. I suspect you're doing this because of the doubled backslash characters you have, which you don't want python to interpret as a single escaped backslash character. However, the raw literal is also preventing `\n` from being interpreted as a newline character.

The only fixes are to keep the the raw string literal separate from the newline, then join them (like you are already doing), or to use a regular string literal and escape your backslashes:

```
str_output = 'name = %(name)s, some_dir = \\\\folder0\\\\..., description = "%(des)s\n'
```

Comment: Type double slashes to input one is make me going insane. :^D... If there are lots of '\' in one string, wow, that will need lots of typing '\\\\\'.

Comment: Yes, I think the way you said in the question that you're doing it now is probably best for your current situation. `r"stuff\\with\\backslashes\"+"\n"`

Answer (score 2):

As already noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58008355/1959808), use parentheses to combine [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) and ordinary strings by [implicit concatenation of string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation). Using also [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals), which are available in Python >= 3.6, the result is:

```py
name = 'some_name'
des = 'some decription'
message = (rf'{name = !s}s, some_dir = \folder0\..., description = {des}s' '\n')
print(message)
```

Comment: Nice input. The new syntax have a more intuitive answer for this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to put escape sequences in raw strings. I would use the same workaround as you.